# How to give relative path in java getResources()

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource, getresource

I am using eclipse juno for the java application and want to load an image on application and for that I am writing following code

```
 URL imageURL = LoginWindow.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/img/pause.png");
```

which gives the following error

> Resource not found: resources/img/pause.png
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: creating TrayIcon with null Image at java.awt.TrayIcon.(Unknown Source)

but if I put the image in the folder where my java file is and remove all path and give only "pause.png" then it works properly.

Comment: When using getResource, the path is relative to the class requesting it, if the path doesn't start with "/"

Answer (score 4):

The class loader that is obtained using that form of call would probably ***not*** be the context class loader intended for loading application resources.  I would recommend instead:

```
LoginWindow lw = new LoginWindow();
// exactly as below, including leading /
URL url = lw.getClass().getResource("/resources/img/pause.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the Class Relative path from their you can refer to the the image

[image]

```
      ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    String imgUrl =classLoader.getResource(".").getPath()+   
                                       "../resources/img/pause.png";
```

By using the imgUrl you do your what operation you want to do .

Comment: this is so useful but not  give proper output it can not find the image.... it return following path Path is :- /D:/Project/Time%20Monitoring%20System/bin/../resources/img/pause.png

Answer (score -1):

Give the structure of your project please.
If you have a Maven project, your code should be as follows:

```
URL imageURL = LoginWindow.class.getClassLoader().getResource("src/main/resources/img/pause.png");
```

Comment: my resources is out side the src folder

Comment: This would still be false. Maven puts everything from `/src/main/resources` into the root of the classpath

Comment: Give the structure of your project please.

Answer (score -1):

try this if you are  running in an applet

```
URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "resources/img/pause.png");
```

Comment: 1) There is no indication this is an applet.  In fact ` Exception in thread "main" ` suggests a frame based app. 2) The `getResource(..)` method works exactly the same for an applet as it does for an application.